# Generating number list for mail merge

Tags: excel

Trying to print a lot of labels, I need column A in excel to read something like.

```
EH001`
EH001
EH001
EH001
EH002
EH002
EH002
EH002
EH003.......
```

I will need to do this for thousands of samples, Whats the easiest way to generate this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim NextRow As Long
NextRow = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlup).Row + 1

For i = 1 To 10000 'or however many you need
    If i < 10 Then
        Range("A" & NextRow).Value = "EH00" & i
    ElseIf i >= 10 And i < 100 Then
        Range("A" & NextRow).Value = "EH0" & i
    ElseIf i >= 100 And i < 1000 Then 
        Range("A" & NextRow).Value = "EH" & i
    End If ' You can go on like this for as much as you need.
Next i
```

Comment: Got this working in the end, However in the short term I made a drag down list (1, 2, 3, 4 ect ect..) Copied it into the same column 4 times, Then used a filter to sort!!

Comment: Nice! glad I could help, already forgot about this question haha